# Routing download link in Laravel 4

Tags: php, file, laravel, routes

I am working on a project based on Laravel 4.
I am trying to save some result to a file and offer it to users so they can download it.

It seems Laravel has its own routing mechanism. I made a directory in the public folder and tried `URL::to` function for a routing to the file.

I think `URL::to` is mainly used for links to the pages, is there any other method to access a file in the public folder or probably storage folder?

```
  $fp = fopen(URL::to('download/file.csv'), 'w');
  fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");
  fputcsv($fp,$cols,'$');
.... writing result ...
 fclose($fp);
 return "Done! <a href='".URL::to('download/file.csv')."' >Download</a>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use laravel facades to do these things "cleaner", like the public_path and File facade:

```
Route::get('file', function()
{
    $path = public_path('test.txt');
    $file = File::put($path, 'contents');
    return "<a href='".$path."'>Download</a>";
});
```

Or open the download immediately:

```
Route::get('file', function()
{
    $path = public_path('test.txt');
    $file = File::put($path, 'contents');
    return Response::download($path);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please consider to vote the question if you found it interesting, i have made some modification on it.

Answer (score 1):

If `download` directory is inside public folder you can use `asset()` method to get the url, and `public_path()` to get the path.

```
  $fp = fopen(public_path().'/download/file.csv', 'w');
  fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");
  fputcsv($fp,$cols,'$');
.... writing result ...
 fclose($fp);
 return "Done! <a href='".asset('download/file.csv')."' >Download</a>";
```

See [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers).